# Continuous Integration data from database

Tags: database, continuous-integration

I have read a lot of stuff about CI and databases on the blog of K. Scott Allen and the book "*Continuous Integration, improving software quality and reducing risk*" from Paul M. Duvall.
But I still have a couple of questions regarding the data from the database:

What if I changed my database in a way that the database should be rebuild. In that case I can run al my create/drop/alter scripts from my VCS and my database would be up and running. EXCEPT MY DATA.
There is relatively simple solution on the development and test environment, but a big deal on my QA and production environment. How do I handle my data in my deployments?

Does anyone have experience with this or does anyone have good blog posts about this?

Comment: Wouldn't that defeat the purpose? Recreate the db I mean. Controlling the DB schema in an incremental way means that all changes are actually alterations, versioned, and ran in a specific order.
Each script modifies the previous state of the database, not regenerating it from scratch. That's if you do it manually, and not through tools for calculating diffs betweent DBs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I have to tell that I have not read the book and as a result I have no idea about the included automation code and the tasks/cases covered by this code.

I'm not so sure how you define the necessity of database rebuild.

The common case is to change a database schema in development and synchronize it on other environments (usually with utilities). Changes may also involve the presence of new tables with data (i.e. new look-up tables), requiring data sync. If everything is developed and tested well, and the synchronization is accurate, then there are no problems with Q.A. and Production environments. But it is a good practice to also have a rollback solution (which is the first that should be tested).

Rarely(?) changes to a database require internal data migration. This is a totally different case, with a mandatory rollback plan. From my experience a case like this, is translated to serious down-time. A good example is hays.com (worldwide recruitment); they changed one by one their countries sites databases to a common schema with down-time for all domains in 2011 (weekends).

Please let me know if I'm missing your point.